# Is there any command line tool to format dart code?

Tags: dart, sublimetext, formatter, command-line-tool

I want to use sublime to write dart code. It has a dart plugin which can highlight the syntax, but can't format it.

I searched and found there is no plugin for sublime for now to format the dart code, so I want to find a command line tool, and invoke it from my sublime.

Is there such a tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dart team has started to work on a code formatter inside the [Analyzer package](http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/analyzer_experimental) but it's still a work in progress. You can have a look at the [CodeFormatter class](http://code.google.com/p/dart/source/browse/branches/bleeding_edge/dart/pkg/analyzer_experimental/lib/src/services/formatter_impl.dart?r=24255#71). You can also follow the corresponding issue : [Dart formatter](http://dartbug.com/2059).

Answer (score 2):

This answer is not about a command line tool, but if you have WebStorm, there is a Dart plugin for it under Settings->Plugins.

After you have installed it, you can just open any file and press <kbd>ctrl+shift+f</kbd> to format it.

Answer (score 1):

for the command line: [dartfmt: The Dart Code Formatter](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/dartfmt/)

In DartEditor this can now be done using the context menu inside the code window and choose 'Format' or just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>

Comment: I wonder why not *Ctrl+Shift+f*. That way it could have been in line with standard eclipse shourtcuts.

Answer (score 0):

`dart format .` will format all files in the directory.